# Why are there errors in this code? Is it because of the curly braces?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm very new to programming. I am trying to write code but I keep getting errors. Would someone be able to tell me why there are errors in the code below?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am very new to programming.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void);

int x = get_int ("x: ");
int y = get_int("y: ");

if (x < y);
{
printf("x is less than y\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out the guide on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- specifically, be sure to include what the errors you are getting say, and what you expect to happen instead. Also, be careful with those `;`s

Comment: No, it's not because you have curly braces, if because of the *lack* of curly braces (you need more!). Please save yourself a lot of time by getting a beginners book about C.

Comment: Go back to the very first lesson in your text book, the one which presents a HelloWorld program. Use that as a foundation for your own experiments.

Comment: C is not a scripting language like python or perl, where you can have free-standing code. In C, every piece of executable code must be placed inside a function. Entry point of a programme is the `main` function, i. e. it is *this* function that will be called at very first when you start your programme.

Comment: Additionally: Have a close look at `if((x < y);`, the trailing semicolon will terminate the statement, so you'll do nothing on the if and execute the subsequent code *un*conditionally (i. e. always).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put bracket when you define the main, with the ";" it's mean it's the end of the line of function so your main doesn't contain anything at the moment. Same for your `if` statement. Your code should look like this

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int "enter name variable here" = "enter value here";

    if ("enter condition here") {
        "things to do then";
    }
}
```